# Get union of objects when pick attributes on union of objects

Tags: typescript

```
type A = {type: 'TypeA', attr1: string}
type B = {type: 'TypeB', attr2: string}
type U = A | B
```

type X = Pick<U, 'type'>
gives me:

```
{ type: 'TypeA' | 'TypeB' }
```

What I want is:

```
{ type: 'TypeA' } | { type: 'TypeB' }
```

How to achieve want I want with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distribute your `Pick` over all members of the union. To do that, use conditional types.

```
type A = {type: 'TypeA', attr1: string}
type B = {type: 'TypeB', attr2: string}
type U = A | B

type PickDistributed<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends any ? Pick<T, K> : never

type X = PickDistributed<U, 'type'>
```